# How to predict the next value of random function ? In a dice problem

Tags: python, random, dice

```
Import random

A= random.randint(1,6)
Print(A)
```

1. I have tried writing this code
2. I want to predict the next value of random function

Comment: Can you tag the language you are using? Have you tried to write anything at all to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In software, we generate random numbers by calling a function called a “random number generator”. Such functions have hidden states, so that repeated calls to the function generate new numbers that appear random. If you know this state, you can predict all future outcomes of the random number generators. O’Neill, a professor at Harvey Mudd college, advocates against using random number generators that make such predictions trivially easy.